# React MaterialTable editable row validation - how to show and hide error?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-table

I have a material-table and I want to run field validations on row editing **only when the user clicks in save button**.

I have this function to set the error:

```
const [nameError, setNameError] = useState({
        error: false,
        label: '',
        helperText: '',
    });
```

And the `onRowUpdate`:

```
onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        setTimeout(() => {

                            if (newData.name === '') {
                                setNameError({
                                    error: true,
                                    label: 'required',
                                    helperText: 'Required helper text'
                                });
                                reject();
                                return;
                            }

                            resolve();
                            if (oldData) {
                                setState(prevState => {
                                    const data = [...prevState.data];
                                    data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
                                    return { ...prevState, data };
                                });
                            }
                        }, 600);
                    })
```

I can set the error, the problem is if I click on cancel button, next time I click on edit the error continues visible.

Here is a gif:

[image]

I tried to look for an event something like **onCancelEdit** but I didn't find anything, do you know how to solve this?

You can try this in
[image: Edit MaterialTableDemo - validation error]

Complete React component code:

```
const tableIcons = {
    Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Delete: forwardRef((props, ref) => <DeleteOutline {...props} ref={ref} />),
    DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Edit: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Export: forwardRef((props, ref) => <SaveAlt {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Filter: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FilterList {...props} ref={ref} />),
    FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FirstPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
    LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <LastPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
    NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
    PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronLeft {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ResetSearch: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Search {...props} ref={ref} />),
    SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowDownward {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ThirdStateCheck: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Remove {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ViewColumn: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ViewColumn {...props} ref={ref} />)
};



export default function MaterialTableDemo() {

    const [nameError, setNameError] = useState({
        error: false,
        label: '',
        helperText: '',
    });



    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        data: [
            {
                name: 'Mehmet',
                surname: 'Baran'
            },
            {
                name: 'Zerya Betül',
                surname: 'Baran'
            },
        ],
    });

    return (
        <MaterialTable
            title="Editable Example"
            columns={
                [
                    {
                        title: 'Name', field: 'name',
                        editComponent: (props) => (
                            <TextField
                                type="text"
                                error={nameError.error}
                                helperText={nameError.helperText}
                                value={props.value ? props.value : ''}
                                onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
                            />
                        )
                    },
                    { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' }
                ]}
            data={state.data}
            icons={tableIcons}
            editable={{
                onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        setTimeout(() => {

                            if (newData.name === '') {
                                setNameError({
                                    error: true,
                                    label: 'required',
                                    helperText: 'Required helper text'
                                });
                                reject();
                                return;
                            }

                            resolve();
                            if (oldData) {
                                setState(prevState => {
                                    const data = [...prevState.data];
                                    data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
                                    return { ...prevState, data };
                                });
                            }
                        }, 600);
                    })
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the value exists in `editComponent`.

```
const [nameError, setNameError] = useState({
    error: false,
    label: "",
    helperText: "",
    validateInput: false
});

columns={[
  {
    title: "Name",
    field: "name",
    editComponent: props => (
    <TextField
        type="text"
        error={
        !props.value && nameError.validateInput
            ? nameError.error
            : false
        }
        helperText={
        !props.value && nameError.validateInput
            ? nameError.helperText
            : ""
        }
        value={props.value ? props.value : ""}
        onChange={e => {
        if (nameError.validateInput) {
            setNameError({
            ...nameError,
            validateInput: false
            });
        }

        props.onChange(e.target.value);
        }}
    />
    )
  },
  { title: "Surname", field: "surname" }
]}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/materialtabledemo-validation-error-kgnww)

Comment: Thanks, but it does not have the desired behaviour. If you edit, delete the name and save, it shows the error. After that, if you cancel de edit and edit again, when the name is deleted the error becomes visible without clicking on the save button

Comment: The edited answer above does the desired behaviour. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can fix with ternary conditional operator.
example :

```
const columns = [
{
  field: 'fieldName',
  title: 'fieldName Titl',
  validate: (rowData) =>
    rowData.fieldName === undefined
      ? { isValid: false, helperText: 'Name cannot be empty' }
      : rowData.fieldName === ''
      ? { isValid: false, helperText: 'Name cannot be empty' }
      : true
}
```

Comment: is there a way to validate once the check icon (add row icon) is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

```
columns = [
  { title: "ID", field: "id", editable: 'never' },
  {
      title: "Last Name", field: "lastName",
      validate: rowData => {
          if (rowData.lastName === undefined || rowData.lastName === "") {
              return "Required"
          }
          return true
      }
  },
  {
      title: "Email", field: "email", filterPlaceholder: "filter",
      validate: rowData => {
          if (rowData.email === undefined || rowData.email === "") {
              return "Required"
          } else if (!rowData.email.includes('@' && '.') || (rowData.email.length < 3)) {
              return "Email is not valid"
          }
          return true
      }
  },
  {
      title: "Gender", field: "gender", lookup: { Male: "Male", Female: "Female" },
      validate: rowData => {
          if (rowData.gender === undefined || rowData.gender === "") {
              return "Required"
          }
          return true
      }
  },
  { title: "Status", field: "status", type: "boolean" }
];
```

source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqk_M23bM_Q

https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/validation